# log4j for threads with different output files/configs

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I have an application that do some jobs and generate logs.
I use org.apache.log4j.Logger
In my class I wrote:

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class);
```

inside main I load properties from file

```
 PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

And write output

```
 logger.debug("Hello World!");
```

All works fine (contents of log4j.properties see below)

Now I want to rewrite an application that will generate different threads (they will be scheduled job and may be executed in parallel).
As I understand the each thread must create the own logger. Something like this:

```
public class TestJob implements Job {
    private Logger thread_logger = null;
    //...
}
```

Now (in the "do thread" method ) I want to setup properties for this logger.

```
thread_logger = Logger.getLogger(TestJob.class); 
//and assign the configuration, but how?
PropertyConfigurator.configure("mythreadname.log4j.properties"); //?
```

The original logger has a log4j.properies file (here output file declared):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.File=.\\streambackup.execution.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Duplicate log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Is it possible (and how to do it) - to link one .property file for each thread (with different output file)?
I.e. I want to do that

```
main thread writes log to log\logmain.txt 
thread1 writes log to log\trh1\log1.txt 
thread2 writes log to log\trh2\log2.txt 
...
threadN writes log to log\trhN\logN.txt 
//I don't now the count of treads...
```

It seems that PropertyConfigurator is a global for all thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create one configuration file per thread but you can add an appender programmatically. e.g.:

```
public static class TestJob implements Job {

    private Logger logger;
    private RollingFileAppender appender;

    private void init() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(TestJob.class);
        appender = new RollingFileAppender();
        appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"));
        appender.setFile("logs/trh1/log1.txt");
        appender.setAppend(false);
        appender.setMaxFileSize("100MB");
        appender.setMaxBackupIndex(10);
        appender.activateOptions();
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.addAppender(appender);
    }

    private void destroy() {
        logger.removeAppender(appender);
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        init();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                logger.info("This is " + i);
            }
        }

        destroy();
    }

}
```

You may want to see the [*Short introduction to log4j: Ceki Gülcü, March 2002*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly what I need. When i start 2 or more jobs of same class i got the mess in files. The appender is merged :)
In the first file I got messages from each thread: 
2015-02-02/23:39:00.027/MSK INFO  TestJob:57 - Starting TestJob: BackupGroup.testJob1 from SBScheduler_Worker-1
2015-02-02/23:39:00.048/MSK INFO  TestJob:57 - Starting TestJob: BackupGroup.testJob2 from SBScheduler_Worker-2 
2015-02-02/23:39:02.049/MSK INFO  TestJob:59 - Finishing TestJob: BackupGroup.testJob2 from SBScheduler_Worker-2 at ...

Comment: I think I solve this problem by renaming the appender: See below

Comment: I think my solution can give you some idea for building your own solution. Did you see the `e.g.`?

Answer (score 1):

This is my working (I hope) update of code by Paul Vargas
At first I rewrite the init function call. I based name by Job identity:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jExeCtx) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobKey jobKey = jExeCtx.getJobDetail().getKey();
        String OutputForLog = jExeCtx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getString(PR_LOGFILNAME); //<--Here I pass the name of the log file from main thread to scheduller job
        init("Thread" + jobKey.toString().replaceAll("\\.", ""), OutputForLog);   //<-- Here I pass the name for appender and the path for log file name
```

And init function now looks like:

```
private Logger logger = null;
private RollingFileAppender appender = null;

private void init(String NameForAppender, String Name4LogFile) {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(NameForAppender); //NOT DEFAULT BY "logger = Logger.getLogger(TestJob.class);"

    appender = new RollingFileAppender();
    appender.setName(NameForAppender); //<-- I think this helps in pair of the Logger.getLogger(NameForAppender) above
    appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"));
    appender.setFile(Name4LogFile);
    appender.setAppend(true);
    appender.setImmediateFlush(true);
    appender.setMaxFileSize("100MB");
    appender.setMaxBackupIndex(10);
    appender.activateOptions();

    logger.setAdditivity(false);    //<--do not use default root logger
    logger.addAppender(appender);
}
```

At least with this code I can't produce log merge in files.
(I start a couple of jobs(threads) based on the same class at the same time)